# Is adjusting Velcro prohibited on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, technology, melacha-creative-work, orach-chaim

According to Halacha, is it permissible to put together or pull apart Velcro straps on Shabbat? Is this considered to be sewing, which is a melacha that is prohibited on Shabbat? Or is it dissimilar to it enough to be permitted?

Sources for the answer to this are appreciated.

Comment: Permitted. https://dinonline.org/2011/06/20/velcro-on-shabbos/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rabbi Ribiat in his Sefer 39 Melochos states on pg 818 that using Velcro is permitted.